# Is it correct to say "the previous resident of the offce"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say "the previous resident of the offce" speaking of the person who used to be in the office I am in right now?

Comment: If you're talking about a *physical* office, I would say *previous occupant*. (*Resident* implies living somewhere.) If you're talking about a job position, then *previous holder* would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The previous resident of this office" sounds slightly humorous, which is fine, as long as the humour is intentional. Otherwise, "previous occupant" is more neutral.